# Is there a way to create an input that only writeable -99 to 99 and nothing else?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need an input in React that only write able -99 to 99 is there a way to achieve this?

i've tried on key down, but it brokes when you try to write double dashes for example;
it works perfectly when you try to write -45 or something.but when you add double dashes then it brokes it becomes writeable anything for example --9909349

also in this function i can write but i shouldn't: 1-9034- etc.

only acceptable: -99 to 99

code:

```
const validateInput = (e) => {
    const currentValue = e.target.value
    const newValue = currentValue + e.key

    if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' || e.key === 'ArrowLeft' || e.key === 'Backspace') {
      return
    }

    if (e.key === '-' && currentValue === '') {
      return
    }

    if (newValue.replace(/0/g, '').length === 0) {
      e.preventDefault()
      return
    }

    if (parseInt(newValue) >= -99 && parseInt(newValue) <= 99) {
      return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }
```

Comment: [input type number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) - [input type range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Comment: which type of input you are using default one ?

Answer (score 0):

The `min` and `max` attributes in the `<input>` tag with type="number" are used to set the range of acceptable values, but they don't prevent the user from manually entering values outside that range.

You can use this logic to restrict the value between -99 to 99.

```js
function validateInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById('numInput');
  var value = input.value;

  var parsedValue = parseInt(value);

  if (isNaN(parsedValue) || parsedValue < -99 || parsedValue > 99) {
    input.value = Math.max(-99, Math.min(99, parsedValue || 0));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numInput" oninput="validateInput()" />
```

Or you can validate `onblur` for better UX. It will validate the input and reset it to the nearest valid value only after the user has finished editing

```js
function validateInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById('numInput');
  var value = input.value;

  var parsedValue = parseInt(value);

  if (isNaN(parsedValue) || parsedValue < -99 || parsedValue > 99) {
    input.value = Math.max(-99, Math.min(99, parsedValue || 0));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numInput" onblur="validateInput()" />
```

Comment: "*but they don't prevent the user from manually entering values outside that range.*" yet the input would still be deemed invalid. And it's an extremely bad practice to just swap out the input a user typed in. One of the most frustrating experiences for me is trying to type the correct value in a form field and the form deciding to change. E.g., I wrote `21` and meant `31`, so I'd position the cursor at the front, type `3`, then press delete to remove the `2`. And yet I'd find I now have what? 99? 9? Whichever it is, it's definitely not what I wanted there.

Comment: Yes @VLAZ you are right that is frustrating but Baran only wants -99 to 99.
The best UX will be validating after the completion of the input.

Comment: @VLAZ I added onblur validation also

Answer (score -4):

In a React application, you can create a component that allows users to input values between -99 and 99 and validate their input. Here's an example of how to create a simple React component to achieve this:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Input() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(value);
    if (/^-?\d+$/.test(value)) {
      const intValue = parseInt(value);

      if (intValue >= -99 && intValue <= 99) {
        setErrorMessage("");
      } else {
        setErrorMessage("Please enter a number between -99 and 99.");
      }
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("");
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorMessage}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please read the [AI ban policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) that forbids the posting of Ai generated content such as answers. We do not need AI mediators here. SO is supposed to have qualified specialists to provide quality answers backed up with actual knowledge. The code that the AI gave you is poorly written and not even a junior dev would do that this way. Just to give you one hint: `ternary conditional operator`